# How to disable MS Word from locking opened files

Tags: microsoft-word, lock

Microsoft Word has a annoying habit of whenever it opens a word file to prevent other runtimes from accessing it.
As far as I can perceive, it's to prevent a lost update scenario with word files.
So whenever I save a file and want to send it by email in an attachment, I'm forced to close word just to be allowed to do that.

How do I prevent Word from monitoring my opened files?
Preferably without decompiling Word that is.

Comment: Word is not "monitoring" your file but rather using Windows' exclusive file access mode, that prevents any other file access. Could you add which version of Word you are using? Newer versions should create a temporary file and only access the original when opening or saving.

Comment: I usually use MS Office 2013. Ought to upgrade though.

Comment: By monitoring files I was refering to this concept here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29
that probably was unclear to most readers.
I guess there is no answer to my question. I guess I have to avoid working for companies that expect us to use Microsoft office and teach myself lateX.

Comment: You are not finding it convenient, but it is very logical that an "editable" files is so locked, because you might have made changes in the file, forgot to save it, and you email or share it, ending up sharing un-saved version while you thought you have made changes so they might have got shared. If you don't want word to lock file, open a read only copy of the same, or open the file in word-viewer that automatically opens read only and doesn't need to lock. If you are not editing the file, why do you keep that open?

Comment: @GiantTree "Newer versions should create a temporary file and only access the original when opening or saving." Could you please mention which newer version of word is doing that, because I have found the same locking behavior in Word 2010-2013-2016-2019. I mean Is their any setting in my newer word to enable unlocking?

Comment: @ VSRawat Windows loves to try to idiotproof their toys. They underestimate two things though, firstly just how much they inconvenience their users who actually know what they do, and secondly the creativity of the users that somehow manage to find ways to misuse their software anyway, safeguard or none.
If I email a file while open then because I intend to continue working on it. The main gripe that is much worse though is when your coworker is editing a file, and went home without closing it.
Good thing I ditched Office and learned to use LateX and Git.